# In Excel VBA, extract range text and sum data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet in which there are multiple rows that have three columns (K, L M) that contain text (inserted manually from a dropdown). The inserted text includes a 'score'. For the row shown in the image that score is 3 + 2 + 2 = 7.

What I'd like to be able to do is to have that score automatically calculated and shown in column N.  I'm happy to do the score extraction given the text, but I'm completey unfamiliar with Excel's object model, and how to write a VBA macro that can be triggered across all of the rows.  I assume it would be passed a range somehow, or a string designating a range, but how to do that is beyond me just now. Perhaps I just need a formula? But one that calls a function to strip non-numerical data from the cell?

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If it is just those three columns and the value is always the first entry then you could use `Left(range, 1)` to extract the value and sum up. If there are multiple columns and the scores are more than 0 to 9 then VBA could be more appropriate

Comment: Yes, just those columns and the scores go 0 to 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this formula in `N2` cell and drag it all the way down.

```
=LEFT(K2, FIND("-", K2)  - 2) + LEFT(L2, FIND("-", L2)  - 2) + LEFT(M2, FIND("-", M2)  - 2)
```

For more information see [reference](https://exceljet.net/formula/split-text-string-at-specific-character). It sum all numbers, that are present before the hyphen (`-`) in a cell.

Comment: That's great - saves me having to macro enable the spreadsheet too.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
N2 = LEFT(TRIM(K2),1) + LEFT(TRIM(L2),1) + LEFT(TRIM(M2),1)
```

As I said in comments, this solution does not scale so well if it is more than three columns and / or the scores are more than single digit `[0-9]`

Comment: Many thanks. Similar to Michal's - saves having the spreadsheet as an xlsm.

Answer (score 1):

A VBA solution to do all of your rows and enter the values into Column N:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
For rownumber = 1 To LastRow 'loop through rows
    For i = 11 To 13 'loop through columns
    strValue = ws.Cells(rownumber, i).Value 'get text string from cell
    pos = InStr(strValue, " -") 'find the dash - in cell
        If pos > 0 Then 'if dash found
            Value = Value + Val(Left(ws.Cells(rownumber, i).Value, pos - 1)) 'remove everything after number
        End If
    Next i
    ws.Cells(rownumber, 14).Value = Value 'write value to column N
    Value = 0
Next rownumber
End Sub
```